# How to train a model on multidimensional complex data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I have an array of input data, these are 5 arrays of different lengths. How to compose the correct tensor and form for training?

```
[
[
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] ],
[
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] ]
],
...
],
]
```

Comment: Each input has to be the same (for example shape 5x5), so you could add zeros in the arrays that are too short.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code to prepare training data set from the multi-dimensional array.

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Your data

data = [
    [
        [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
        [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
    ],
    [
        [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
        [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
        [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
    ],
   
]

flattened_data = [item for sublist1 in data for sublist2 in sublist1 for item in sublist2]
ragged_tensor = tf.ragged.constant(flattened_data, dtype=tf.float32)
print(ragged_tensor)
```